# Bash command output string comparison and using IF ELSE condition

Tags: bash

How do I compare bash command output and use IF ELSE block to do something.

I am trying to capture the bash command output in CMD variable and if the variable is empty / zero, then output that the binary/feature is missing. Pretty basic.

In the below code, the second if else

```
# Check if the CPU supports KVM
cmd=$(grep -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo)
if [[ $cmd -ne 0 ]];then 
    echo "CPU on this machine does not support KVM. Check documentation please"
fi



#!/bin/bash

# Check if KVM kernel modules are installed.
cmd=$(lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | grep -Eiw 'kvm\|kvm_intel\|kvm_amd')
if [[ $cmd -ne 0 ]];then 
    echo "KVM kernel modules kvm or kvm_[intel|amd] missing. Use modprobe to load them please"
fi

# Check if the CPU supports KVM
cmd=$(grep -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo)
if [[ $cmd -ne 0 ]];then 
    echo "CPU on this machine does not support KVM. Check documentation please"
fi
```

Instead of just checking the condition, the script is printing the command output (/proc/cpuinfo), I just want it to print the echo line but not the command output.

Comment: Are you trying to check what `grep` *returns* or what it *outputs* to *stdout*? Those are two different things.`cmd=$(grep ...)` captures the output.

Comment: I am trying to grep a string ... if the string exists then do something and if it doesn't exist in the grep output do something else.

Comment: I know you're trying to grep a string. I was trying to understand what result you were trying to examine from grep. According to the manual page for `grep`, *Normally the **exit status** is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and
       2 if an error occurred.* If you're checking the exit status, then you're going about it the wrong way.  If you want the exit status, then check `$?` right after executing the `grep`. It will have a value of 0 if there was a match. You don't get the exit status using `cmd=$(grep ...)`.

Comment: I am not checking the exit code. What I am trying is the following

cmd=$(grep -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo) <--- storing the output in cmd variable

It could be "someoutput" or "empty"

if [[ $cmd -ne 0 ]];then  <--- checking that condition with this line and doing something with IF and something else with ELSE

but I don't expect $cmd to print something to STDOUT

why is $cmd in if [[ $cmd -ne 0 ]];then  printing to STDOUT is my gripe 

Hope this is explained in a better way?

Comment: If you're not trying to check exit code, then why are you checking the result of `grep` against a `0`? The result of `grep -Eiw 'vmx|svm'...` is either going to be one or more lines that contain `vmx` or `svm`, or no lines at all. In the case of no lines at all, `grep` does not output a 0.

Comment: `if grep -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo; then echo Matched vm; else echo no match ; fi` try that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should check command *exit status*, not it's output.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if KVM kernel modules are installed.
if ! lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | grep -q -Eiw 'kvm|kvm_intel|kvm_amd'; then
    echo "KVM kernel modules kvm or kvm_[intel|amd] missing. Use modprobe to load them please"
fi

# Check if the CPU supports KVM
if ! grep -q -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo; then
    echo "CPU on this machine does not support KVM. Check documentation please"
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if KVM kernel modules are installed.
lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | grep -q -Eiw 'kvm\|kvm_intel\|kvm_amd'
ret=$?
if ((ret != 0)); then
    echo "KVM kernel modules kvm or kvm_[intel|amd] missing. Use modprobe to load them please"
fi

# Check if the CPU supports KVM
grep -q -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo
ret=$?
if ((ret != 0)); then
    echo "CPU on this machine does not support KVM. Check documentation please"
fi
```

Also decide if you use `grep 'vmx\|svm'` or `grep -E 'vmx|svm'`. Escaping `\|` in `-E` will parse `|` as literal character. Here [bashfaq How can I store the return value and/or output of a command in a variable?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) is a good bash introduction.

Also the `grep -Eiw` looks a bit strange. Are you really looking for a modules named `KvM_InTeL` or `kVM_INteL` or `kVm_InTeL`? There is only one module name, it's lowercase - `kvm`, `kvm_intel`, `kvm_amd`. Also using `-w` is irrelevant - `lsmod | awk '{print $1}'` output is already one per line. I would just go with `grep 'kvm\|kvm_intel\|kvm_amd'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this more difficult than need be. You simply need to use a *compound command* to (1) check whether `vmx` or `svm` extensions are present in `/proc/cpuinfo`, and (2) check whether the `kvm` or `kvm_intel` module is loaded by checking `/proc/modules`. Using a *compound command* two calls are all that are needed:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -wq 'vmx\|svm' /proc/cpuinfo || {   ## check CPU support
    printf "error: CPU does not support vmx or svm extensions.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

grep -q '^kvm' /proc/modules || {        ## check modules loaded
    printf "error: CPU supports KVM, but kvm modules not loaded.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

printf "CPU supports KVM and modules present.\n"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/utl/kvmsupport.sh
CPU supports KVM and modules present.
```

You can do it any number of ways, but generally the simpler you can keep it, the less opportunity for error there is.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.

Many of you suggested using exit code which maybe the answer but I was specific about checking if the output result stored in the variable is an empty string or non-empty string and the [[ ]] test condition should not output to STD-OUT, just do a comparison without outputting anything to the terminal.

Second, I didn't want to use -q as it exits with zero status , not only for any match found but also for errors encountered.

Thirdly, I didn't use egrep as it is non-standard and deprecated [Ref:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html]

Lastly, using -i and -w is redundant as the modules will be in lowercase and awk is doing the same as -w [Agreed] but just wanted to avoid assumptions esp that it will always be lowercase.

My Solution:
cmd=$(grep -Eiw 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo)
[[ -z "$cmd" ]] && echo "error: :CPU does not support KVM. Check documentation." && exit 1

-z does not output the return string to the terminal and just tells if the string is empty or non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to get a zero exit code if and only if some pattern is matched is `grep --quiet PATTERN` (or `-q` if you don't have GNU Grep). You can use the same pattern in a pipeline if `grep` is the *last* command in the pipeline or you use `set -o pipefail` to get the first non-zero exit code in the pipeline as the exit code of the whole pipeline.

So in your case it would simply be:

```
if lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | grep -Eiw 'kvm\|kvm_intel\|kvm_amd'
then
    …
```